# Resume, instead Restart, app using URI Launcher

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, uri

I'm trying implement Facebook Login using the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.net/) but I'm having an issue returning back to the app when a login has been successful.

I have followed all the steps in this [tutorial](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/11/14/sign-into-windows-phone-8-apps-with-facebook-login.aspx) but i'm having an issue.

I have created a custom UriMapper that should go back to the MainPage.xaml when launched.

```
public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri) 
{
    if (uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("/Protocol?encodedLaunchUri=msft")) 
    {
       return new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    }

    return uri;
}
```

My problem is the page refreshes and all my data in forms and text boxes gets removed.

Is it possible to "Resume" an app via URI instead of restarting it?

I've tried adding the tag below in the manifest but this does not work.

```
<DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml" ActivationPolicy="Resume"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The part that you added in the manifest file enabled Fast App Resume, which means that your application won't be relaunched as a new instance if it is sitting in the background. But this doesn't guarantee that your input boxes will get their data restored. For this, you need to preserve the page state and restore it when the app resumes. Read more about this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967548%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).